# Not able to identify Restclient(Firefox add on) through selenium.getting different frame error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to access the Headers drop down in the REST Client page(Firefox RESTClient add on) through selenium.

The test case is failing at that point saying

> "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element belongs
>   to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing
>   frame to use it".

belongs to a different frame when there is no frame at all in that page. I checked the page source and no frame tags in the HTML.
Any one have ideas about this or any one have updated code for this

Comment: why do u wish to do rest api testing using selenium..i see jmeter or soapui as best fit for web service testing

Comment: Thanks your response Mrunal.Requirement is to automate restclient through selenium with other app GUI.

Comment: to automate rest services there is no need for selenium..you can on your own make rest calls via java rest api's that way it would be faster reliable and less overhead